# Mac + Cocoa - problem with trackpad scrolling (two fingers)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, trackpad

For some reason when i scroll with trackpad it scrolls in X direction or Y direction and not in both in the same time.

in scrollWheel method, either [event deltaX] == 0 or [event deltaY] == 0

I want to be able to scroll in X and Y direction simultaneously. 
How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `setUsesPredominantAxisScrolling:` method, eg:

```
[view setUsesPredominantAxisScrolling:NO];
```

Comment: Caveat: That's a 10.7 method.  If you are targeting 10.5 or 10.6, you want to see if the view responds to that selector prior to calling it.